# Is it enough to install Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macports

I use OS X El Capitan. I installed Xcode 7 from AppStore and macports from an official website.

When I'm trying to install something using macports: `sudo port install nodejs4`, I'm getting the following warning: `Warning: The Xcode Command Line Tools don't appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.`. But compiler (`cc`) works, `make` works, and I actually installed few macports packages without any problems.

Now if I run `xcode-select --install`, I'm getting dialog to install Developer Tools. But I think that Xcode already has all those tools:

```
$ xcode-select -p
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

So the question is: is it some bug in macports or is there some tools not included with Xcode 7 which must be installed separately using `xcode-select --install`? I don't want to introduce unnecessary clutter.

Comment: If you open Xcode and go to Preferences, does it show command line tools installed? They aren't installed by default, just because you downloaded Xcode (in my experience).

Comment: @ruddfawcett I wasn't able to find anything about command line tools in Xcode 7. I remember that they were there in old versions, but now I can only see emulators and documentation for downloading. I think that Xcode now installs command-line tools automatically.

Comment: @user3439894 I will use Xcode regardless, I just don't want to install additional packages if it's not necessary. Command line tools seem to work fine, unless I missing some. But macports complain and I don't understand, why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I've inspected macports sources and it turns out that this warning is displayed, when directory `/usr/include` or executable `/usr/bin/make` is missing. While I have working `/usr/bin/make`, directory `/usr/include` was indeed missing. Installing command-line tools using `xcode-select --install` fixed it.

Comment: If that was indeed what solved your problem, consider accepting your own answer so that this question no longer shows up in the "unanswered" lists.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the developer tools to run the C compiler and other build tools (e.g. linker, make) from the command line and provide support files e.g. include and libraries

The command line tools  are in places like /usr/bin and so installing via the AppStore cannot put the tools in the correct place. This a separate install step has to be done.

Comment: But those tools are working from terminal right now. There's `/usr/bin/clang` and it works, I can compile C programs. Same about `/usr/bin/make`, `/usr/bin/xcrun`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As a comment on the original question said, you must go to Xcode's settings, then to the last tab, Locations. The options for which command line toolset to use is there.